# How to repackage xml into cab?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, sharepoint, cab

I am trying to implement a list item reordering feature in sharepoint 2010 using this tutorial 
http://sharepointjim.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/how-to-enable-list-item-re-order-in-any-sharepoint-2010-custom-list/

but I am stuck on this step:

Repackage the manfest.xml into a .cab file (You can use visual studio 2010 to generate .CAB))

How can I do this? I have visual studio 2010 by the way.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

see here, is like another type of project
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b8fd8ss(v=vs.80).aspx